# retrieve the most recent date within a query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was able to fix my previous query, however the results retrieve contains duplicates. I want to retrieve the latest record.

For example:

```
   id | firstname | lastname | email             |  date
   1  | steven    | smith    | steven@gmail.com     2013-06-10 04:01:25
   2  | Bill      | Johnson  | bill@gmail.com    |  2014-06-10 04:01:25
   3  | steven    | smith    | steven@gmail.com  |  2014-10-10 12:01:25
```

The return result should be  the row with IDs 2 and 3 
THe ID 1 should be not returned as the date is older than the ID 3 date

How can I add this to the query below ?

```
   SELECT
    users.firstname,
    users.lastname,
    DISTINCT(users.email),
    users.pref
   FROM (
    SELECT
        users.firstname,
        users.lastname,
        users.email,
        users.status,
         users.active,

        CONCAT(
            users.preference_1, ',',
            users.preference_2, ',', 
            users.preference_3
        ) AS pref
    FROM users
) AS users

  WHERE  users.status = 1
  AND users.active = 1
  AND users.date = (
SELECT MAX(u.date) FROM users AS u WHERE u.email =  users.email
  )
  LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: (1) Why are you still using a subquery?  (2) Why isn't the syntax error in `concat()` fixed?

Comment: I have fixed the query, I have to use the subquery!

Comment: Is there any reason other than the date issue to use a subquery? I have a theoretical solution that involves the use of the `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` keywords.

Comment: I still don't understand why rows with ID 2 and 3 need to be returned. Latest one is only row with ID 3.

Comment: IF there is a duplicate email address, it return the most recent date of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like you want to fetch the latest row for each user.

Here's a query that can do it. (It also uses subquery. I don't understand the necessity for using subquery to concat though)

```
SELECT DISTINCT us.email, us.preference FROM users AS us WHERE us.date = (
    SELECT MAX(u.date) FROM users AS u WHERE u.email = us.email
)
```

This does not fetch all the details you want. But gives you the basic idea about the query you might have to run.

Comment: thanks, I have added it to question. It is taking a very long time till now the query has not returned any results

Comment: You forgot the distinct part. Add `DISTINCT(users.email)`. No wonder query is taking a long time. Also, it should be `MAX(u.date)`

Comment: Sorry. DISTINCT is not a function. It is a keyword. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. no need for subselect
2. add: `ORDER BY users.date DESC LIMIT 1` this way you sort the list by date and return only the "1st elemet" which is the one with the "biggest/latest" date

Comment: I need the subselect, because there are multiple columns which need to be merged into one

Comment: Why can't you concat in the first query itself? Say, `SELECT firstname, lastname, email, CONCAT(preference, ',') AS users.pref`?

Comment: there are multiple preference columns, preference_1, preference_2, preference_3, preference_4